# Mysql query won't ORDER BY date

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am stuck with the following query, which won't order by it's date. Any help, or insight into what I am doing wrong will be much appreciated. The query is supposed to get an entry by thread_id, and then show the newest post in the thread, much like with a forum post, which it does fine. But when I try to order the results from newest to oldest using ORDER BY clause, it seems to ignore it.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM messages 
            WHERE (thread_id, received) 
             IN (SELECT thread_id, MAX(received) 
                 FROM messages 
                 WHERE receiver='$user' OR sender='$user' 
                   AND is_hidden_receiver!='1' 
                 GROUP BY thread_id) 
           ORDER BY received DESC";
```

Cheers, Lea

Comment: Doesn't make sense - `SELECT *` includes the `received` column, which is a requirement for some db's.  So `ORDER BY received DESC` should work.

Comment: What is the actual data type of the `received` field?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using, and on which platform?  Superficially, assuming the `received` column actually is a DATE/TIME type, there is no excuse for it not to work - other, perhaps, than a bug in MySQL.

Comment: try specifying the table name table.received desc
Once something similar happened to me, it turned out that my query was constructed in such a way that the order column had the same data for every row

Comment: @Mike, it's a timestamp produced by the php time() function, which is inserted into the DB when the entry is composed.

Comment: I really don't like the omission of parentheses with the combination of AND and OR conditions in the WHERE clause.  Always parenthesize such expressions for clarity.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I agree, I can't see why it's not sorting with the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Also, you should be cautious about SQL injection if the value of '`$user`' is specified by the user.  It probably isn't a problem here, but you should always be aware of Mr O'Reilly or Little Bobby Tables (http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @Lea - That tells me what you are inserting, but not what the type the field is. If it is a DATETIME or VARCHAR and you are inserting an integer value from time(), it will not behave as you expect. Try defining the column as TIMESTAMP and do not specify the value in PHP.

Comment: @Lea: Post the output from `DESCRIBE messages`.  For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html

Comment: @Mick, currently the field type was INT(11), upon changing it to TIMESTAMP, everything is being sorted by date DESC. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mick, could you please post your suggestion as an answer, so I can mark it answered please.

Comment: @all, Thanks everyone for replies!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using the PHP `time()` function to generate a value to be inserted into an `INT(11)` column. I'm a little mystified as to why this was sorting incorrectly. I will update this answer if I figure out how to explain it concisely.

This feature is built into MySQL, it is the `TIMESTAMP` column type. You should probably [read up on it a bit more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) before being happy with this solution. It has some interesting properties, depending on how to define your table, a column of type `TIMESTAMP` can act either as a creation timestamp or a modification timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that it really isn't sorting by "received", or are you just getting different results than you expect? It could be order of operations on the where clause--I'm not sure if AND or OR takes precedence. Maybe try changing this:

```
receiver='$user' OR sender='$user' AND is_hidden_receiver!='1'
```

to whichever one of these you are wanting:

```
(receiver='$user' OR sender='$user') AND is_hidden_receiver!='1'

receiver='$user' OR (sender='$user' AND is_hidden_receiver!='1')
```

Comment: Without the brackets is the same as `receiver='$user' OR (sender='$user' AND is_hidden_receiver!='1')`

Comment: thanks, i never remember those things (i always use parens when mixing AND and OR just to be safe)

Comment: I agree with the sentiment about bracketing mixed AND and OR terms - and said as much in a comment - but that probably isn't the source of the trouble.